# Mongodb KeyFile too open permissions

Tags: mongodb, permissions

I have created a three members replicaSet (in separated servers) following the tutorial on mongodb site.

I have configure in /etc/mongodb.conf the following:

fork=true

keyFile=/srv/mongodb/keyFile

And I have create the keyFile in that location and the server always told me "permissions are too open" in keyFile

What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry does that answer mean those permissions need to be on the entire path or just on the keyfile? Because that answer is exactly what the Mongo manual says (chmod 600 /path/to/keyfile) with the only difference being that the manual says 400 permissions but doesn't make it any clearer whether the entire path needs to have that level of permissions.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#security-considerations-for-replica-sets):

> The key file must not have group or “world” permissions on UNIX systems

Therefore if you run this, you should be fine (substitute actual path):

```
chmod 600 /path/to/keyfile
```

You should also make sure that the keyfile is owned by the same user that you use to run the mongod/mongos processes, otherwise setting the permissions above will cause an error (only the user that owns the file can access it with 600 permissions).

Comment: I found the problem. Mongodb is running on the user mongodb and the file was created with another user. Using chown mongodb keyFile solved my problem. 
Adam, I did that following de tutorial and I got cannot read file. 
Now all is Ok

Comment: Sorry - I thought that was implied.  The 700 permissions mean that only the owner of the file can access it, hence that owner needs to be the same one you are using to run the MongoDB processes.  I added a note to clarify for others

Comment: I can understand why it disallows world permissions, but disallowing groups just seems a step too far and complicates admin.

Comment: It's actually fairly standard for this kind of file - take a look at the permissions on ssh keys and such

Comment: 600 is more correct mode 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/generate-key-file/#create-a-key-file

Comment: as of today 400 is more correct mode:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/

Comment: I see that the docs now refer to a 400 permission, but without changing all parent directory permissions there is no functional difference in terms of security. It takes one extra command to write/overwrite the file - that's it.