# Security/Authorization between replica sets in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, set

I have setup 3 nodes as replica sets in Mongo. All are communicating fine but when I enable authorization I couldn't figure out how to still get them to communicate.

- I get them to all replicate fine
- I enable auth=true in the mongod.conf on a secondary

I get the following problem:

```
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "50.17.?.?:27017",
                    "health" : 0,
                    "state" : 6,
                    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                    "uptime" : 0,
                    "optime" : {
                            "t" : 1366321962,
                            "i" : 1
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-04-18T21:52:42Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-04-18T22:04:52Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 81,
                    "authenticated" : false,
                    "syncingTo" : "54.244.?.?:27017"
```

When I disable auth by setting it to false it obviously works.  Now I may be new to this but not dumb.  I do know that it can't connect because I enabled authorization.  But where on earth would a person configure for the primary to sync with an auth=true secondary? Or is there any other solutions on how to enable communication between replica sets while forcing clients the need to authorize> I looked everywhere to no avail.

If it is not possible what are alternatives to authorization besides just using a firewall? What if someone compromises a trusted system by IP. I would not want them to be able to connect to a secondary or primary without a password. For example if my office gets compromised and the mongo primary is trusting our office IP.

Comment: you use keyFiles for authentication between replica sets. what doesn't make sense is to enable auth on a single replica node only.

Comment: I was just testing it out to see what happens so I can get the primary to connect to an authorized instance.  I was intending to go on completely to set it up on all nodes. I will try this out. Asya your amazingly fast.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: might you guys update the docs on replica sets (e.g. [deployment](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)) to include something about security? That aspect is completely overlooked in all the replica set docs.mongodb.org pages I've checked.

Comment: security is a pretty big section in the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-introduction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Asya and the article I found below I was able to allow the authorizations of users and to also have the replicas communicate with the keyfile (shared between all replicas). To emphasize you can not have replicas communicate with users the way some other RDBMS work.

You have to remember to chmod the files or else the mongod instance will not start saying that the keyfile is "too open". Its trying to protect you from having a key that is showing to non essential linux users/groups. You also have to make sure you chown to the mongod (in my case) user.

[Mongodb KeyFile too open permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789622/mongodb-keyfile-too-open-permissions)